# SQL query Oracle based

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a little trouble alternating this table :

my table is `styles` (`id, style`)

```
id    Style      
------------
01   Style-01 
02   Style-02 
03   Style-03
04   Table
06   Chair
```

I need to change the word "Style-XX" to Coach-XX, where XX is an even number (0, 2, 4, 6).

So it looks like this:

```
id    Style      
------------
01   Coach-02 
02   Style-03 
03   Coach-04
04   Table
06   Chair
```

Well, I know that It must be like this: XX mod 2 = 0, in order a number to be even (0, 2, 4 etc).

But I really don't know how to separate the words :S

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing to me because the words don't quite match your example.  At any rate, how about using a simple `UPDATE` step, something like this:

```
update your_table
from (
   select id
        , case
             when Style = 'Style-01' then 'Coach-02'
             when Style = 'Style-03' then 'Coach-04'
             when Style = 'Style-05' then 'Coach-06'
             when Style = 'Style-07' then 'Coach-08'
             when Style = 'Style-09' then 'Coach-00'
             end as new_style
   from  your_table
   where Style in ('Style-01','Style-03','Style-05'
                   'Style-07','Style-09'
   ) x

set Style = x.new_style

where your_table.id = x.id
```

I think it's better to do things explicitly rather than trying to parse a value and do arithmetic.  Something like this is much easier to follow in case you need to revisit the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
MERGE INTO style s
USING (
   SELECT id
   FROM style ss
   WHERE ss.style LIKE 'Style%'
   AND  mod(to_number(substr(ss.style,6)),2)=0)e
   ON (s.id = e.id
      )
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET style =replace(style,'Style','Coach');
```

SQLFIDDLE :[link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30dd3/6)

Answer (score 0):

If your need is to change the data:

```
update STYLES set STYLE = 'Coach-'||substr(STYLE,-2,2)
where STYLE like 'Style-__'
  and substr(STYLE,-2,2) between '00' and '99'
  and mod(to_number(substr(STYLE,-2,2)),2) = 0;
```

If you only need to transform while reading the data:

```
select 
  ID
 ,case
    when STYLE like 'Style-__'
     and substr(STYLE,-2,2) between '00' and '99'
     and mod(to_number(substr(STYLE,-2,2)),2) = 0
    then 'Coach-'||substr(STYLE,-2,2)
    else STYLE
  end as STYLE
from STYLES;
```